# hand cranked ceramic conical burr coffee grinder?

Tags: coffee

I would very much like a recommendation for a manual ceramic burr grinder for turkish coffee. The grinder must be able to do fine powder consistently. Effort is no problem.

Thank you.

Comment: I think your question is in danger of being closed in its current form for either being too broad or off topic. It may fare better if you change the focus to ask about the defining qualities of different grinders and their relative worth with regards to your requirements. If you have done some initial research, it may help to give details.

Comment: As Chris Steinbach said, shopping recommendations for a specific brand or model are off topic here. Asking what to look for in a grinder (such that the answers are a list of criteria) is OK, but you seem to already know what you want and just need a product which fulfills it. If I misunderstood and you still need criteria for choosing, edit the question and we will reopen.

Answer (score 1):

As much as your question in its current form might be off-topic, I like this grinder so much as to answer the question anyway. :) Hopefully not too much shame on me...?

Hario is a brand with many good manual and ceramic burr grinders. I like [this one](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/2692477290986271602?q=hario+burr+grinder). You say effort is okay, but it will take *a lot* of effort to get beans down to Turkish-level powder.

That said, a web-search for "manual ceramic burr coffee grinder" returns many results. We're you not happy with those, or wanted reviews? For my cost-benefit equation, I'd buy the tin of pre-ground.

Comment: I don't know how fine "Turkish-level powder" needs to be, but I have that grinder, and I recommend it. It's cheap, and gets the job done.